# Performance and raster rendering problems with QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, raster, import, rendering

I recently switched from QGIS version 3.22 to version 3.28 and since then I have had problems importing (drag and drop) raster data. When I import the same image with only 2 bands, QGIS in 3.22 uses paletted and the performance is perfect. In 3.28 multi-band is used as default (image), which means that the image is green and performance suffers greatly (even with grids with 3 bands, the performance is much worse in 3.28).

Are there new rendering options in 3.28?

[image]